# Why is the PATINDEX returning wrong results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, patindex

I am trying to extract the date from a string. I am using the below mentioned query using both SUBSTRING and PATINDEX:

```
SELECT Message, SUBSTRING(Message, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', Message), 10) as Month_Captured
```

I am confused by the results "CONTROL V", please see the attached image. Can you please explain why this is happening and what is the best way to extract the date from a string.

[image: SQL QUERY RESULTS]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and produce a [mre] without imnages as described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You're *picture* looks like SQL Server, your query looks like T-Sql, but you've tagged *MySql*.

Comment: also patindex only exist ion sql server mysql has no such function

Comment: I have updated the tags.

Comment: Hints: what does `SUBSTRING(Message, 0, 10)` return? How about `PATINDEX(«your pattern», Message)`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle a no-match case from CHARINDEX is to coerce the 0 to a null with the `NULLIF(value, 0)` function. This will in turn cause the SUBSTRING to also yield null.

```
DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(100) = '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'

SELECT
    Message,
    SUBSTRING(Message, NULLIF(PATINDEX(@Pattern, Message),0), 10) as Month_Captured
FROM Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're after a valid date, you could wrap your existing criteria with *try_convert* that will either return a valid date or NULL

```
SELECT Message, 
  Try_Convert(date, 
    SUBSTRING(Message, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', Message), 10)
  ) as Date_Captured
```